# Conditional css depending on content

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

How can I style or add class to a css element depending on content type.
My example: I wish to add class or style a p element when it contain an iframe like this.

```
<p><iframe frameborder="0" height="400" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0" scrolling="no" src="https://www.hashdoc.com/documents/185392/embed" style="border:1px solid #EAE9EA; border-width:1px; margin-bottom:5px; max-width: 100%;" title="Les résultats aux examens" width="550"></iframe></p>
```

So it could be something like that:

```
if p contain iframe add class 'myclass' to p
```

Can I do that with sass or do I need js?

EDIT: my final jquery code

```
$(".page-lycee p:has(iframe)").addClass('external-content');
```

Comment: if you want to apply only first child (if it is iframe) then basically by css you can do it i.e. `p > iframe { your css }` and if you want to apply every iframe in p tag then directly use `p iframe { css }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as i know it's currently not possible with CSS. You can fix this with jQuery though.

**Example code:**

```
$('p:has(iframe)').addClass('myclass');
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `.has()` to check if `p` has `iframe` like follow:

```js
$("p").has("iframe").addClass('myClass');
```

```css
.myClass{
  background:red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>
  <iframe frameborder="0" height="400" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0" scrolling="no" src="https://www.hashdoc.com/documents/185392/embed" style="border:1px solid #EAE9EA; border-width:1px; margin-bottom:5px; max-width: 100%;" title="Les résultats aux examens"
    width="550">
  </iframe>
</p>

<p> This will not have the class "myClass"</p>
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use the jQuery selector `:has()`

```
$("p:has(iframe)").css("border", "solid red");
```

example:
https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/sel_has.asp